# Nginx Domain Forwarding not working : localhost.test.com’s server IP address could not be found

Tags: nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I was trying to redirect a local domain called 'https://localhost.test.com', to 127.0.0.1:3000 using nginx
Currently http://localhost:3000 is working. https://localhost:443 works as well but somehow localhost.test.com returns : localhost.test.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Operating system: Windows

I generated SSL certificates using openssl and stored the crt and key files in a folder inside C drive which I have mentioned here in NGINX conf below

Here's the config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

   # gzip  on;
   # brotli on;
   # brotli_static on;
   # brotli_comp_level 11;
   # brotli_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json image/svg+xml application/xml+rss;
  server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
  }


  # HTTPS server
  server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      C:\LocalCertificates\localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:\LocalCertificates\localhost.key;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    server_name          localhost.test.com;
    server_tokens        off;
    
    
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
      add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';";
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
      add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin";
    } 
        
  } 
}
```

I was expecting it successfully redirects me to 127.0.0.1:3000